# Working with Foreign keys in JpaRepository

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, repository

I am developing simple API for practice project Online Shopping system. Since I am very new in working with APIs, I am having a trouble with my Entities and relationships. First, I give all my schema and classes before introduce the problem.

Here is a [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sc3Vp.png) for my database schema.

These are `@Entity` classes:

```
----
@Entity
@Table(name = "Customer")
public class Customer {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "id")
private int id;

@Column(name = "name")
private String name;

@Column(name = "country")
private String country;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "customer", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
private List<Order> orders = new ArrayList<>();

// constructor, getters, setters ....


@Entity
@Table(name = "Order")
public class Order {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "id")
private int id;

@Column(name = "date")
private Date date;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "cust_id", nullable = false)
@JsonIgnore
private Customer customer;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "order", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
private List<Detail> details = new ArrayList<>();

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "order", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
private List<Invoice> invoices = new ArrayList<>();

//constructor, setters, getters ....

@Entity
@Table(name = "Product")
public class Product {

@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column(name = "id")
private int id;

@Column(name = "name")
private String name;

@Column(name = "description")
private String description;

@Column(name = "price")
private Double price;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "product", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
private List<Detail> orderDetails = new ArrayList<>();

//cons, setters, getters ...

@Entity
@Table(name = "Detail")
public class Detail {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private int id;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "ord_id", nullable = false)
@JsonIgnore
private Order order;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "pr_id", nullable = false)
@JsonIgnore
private Product product;

@Column(name = "quantity")
private int quantity;

//similar classes for Invoice and Payment (no problem with them)
```

Here is my Sample Repository class:

```
@Repository
public interface ProductRepository extends JpaRepository<Product, Integer> {

}
```

Also here is my controller class:

```
@RestController
public class OnlineShoppingApiController {
@Autowired
ProductRepository productRepository;

@Autowired
OrderRepository orderRepository;

@Autowired
CustomerRepository customerRepository;

@Autowired
DetailRepository detailRepository;

@Autowired
InvoiceRepository invoiceRepository;

@Autowired
PaymentRepository paymentRepository;

@GetMapping("/products")
public List<Product> getProductsList(){
    return productRepository.findAll();
}

@GetMapping("/customers")
public List<Customer> getCustomersList(){
    return customerRepository.findAll();
}

@GetMapping("/orders")
public List<Order> getOrdersList(){
    return orderRepository.findAll();
}

@GetMapping("/invoices")
public List<Invoice> getInvoicesList(){
    return invoiceRepository.findAll();
}

@GetMapping("/payments")
public List<Payment> getPaymentsList(){
    return paymentRepository.findAll();
}

@GetMapping("/details")
public List<Detail> getDetailsList(){
    return detailRepository.findAll();
}
```

I am doing the same approach for all APIs and relationships.

When I call for /products in postman, I am getting result JSON like this:

```
[{
    "id": 3,
    "name": "pname_816",
    "description": "pdesc_871_871_871_87",
    "price": 1.41,
    "orderDetails": [
        {
            "id": 9,
            "quantity": 831
        },
        {
            "id": 51,
            "quantity": 701
        },
        {
            "id": 87,
            "quantity": 310
        }
    ]
},
{
    "id": 4,
    "name": "pname_395",
    "description": "pdesc_495_495_495_49",
    "price": 26.65,
    "orderDetails": [
        {
            "id": 85,
            "quantity": 853
        }
    ]
}]
```

Same fine results for `/details`, `/invoices`, and `/payments`.

The problem is if I send GET request for `/customers`, the result:

```
{
"timestamp": "2018-04-05T11:53:39.558+0000",
"status": 500,
"error": "Internal Server Error",
"message": "Could not write JSON: could not extract ResultSet; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: could not extract ResultSet (through reference chain: java.util.ArrayList[0]->com.example.project.pojo.Customer[\"orders\"])",
"path": "/customers"
}
```

And if i send request for `/orders`, the result is:

```
{
"timestamp": "2018-04-05T11:54:37.316+0000",
"status": 500,
"error": "Internal Server Error",
"message": "could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet",
"path": "/orders"
}
```

The same approach is not working for all. I cannot understand where the problem is. Please help me to find it.

Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have finally found the answer by myself. Here the problem is not with Annotation or key referencing but with the naming the Entities.

Since order is reserved keyword for MySql, naming the entity and variables like this causes unexpected problems.

So I have just changed the Entity name to Orders in schema and code and working fine.

Hope this post will help for others too